# Should flashlights be merged with this beta?

Tags: discussion

[This](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40085/flashlights) has just popped up on area51, and I was wondering about suggesting to merge it into this site. I very much doubt it can survive on its own and most questions about torches / flashlights would probably be on topic here (from a quick think, I'm prepared for the fact I may be wrong!)

What do people think?

Comment: Have to think on it myself.  Seems like there could be many non-outdoor uses for lights.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, the said proposal on Area51 is already deleted.

Answer (score 4):

While there would be a good amount of overlap, looking at the proposed questions, I'm not quite convinced any of the three of them would be on-topic here.  So I don't think it should be closed as a dupe of us. That said, it's so specific I'd be astonished if it even got to the commitment stage.

Comment: +1, I'd also be astonished and on reflection perhaps not all questions would be candidates for a merger!